# Indexing list returned by a function

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, indexing

How do I access elements of a list that is returned by a function?

My function that returns the list is:

`b[x_] := (Return[{x, x/2}];)`

Then when I try to reference an instance of a list by running

`b[0.3][[0]]`

The output I receive is `List`, while the output I'd like to receive in this case is `0.3`

Comment: Must be a C programmer.  The index starts at 1:  `b[0.3][[1]]`.

Comment: From the documentation for [`Part`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html), "Part 0 of an expression is its head."